# Drawing a random double

Tags: swift

I want to generate a random double between 0 and 5. I am doing

`Double.random(in: 0.0…5.0)`

In playground or debugging I get a very nice unified distribution.
In the appstore so far after 100 draws the highest number I got was 0.59. Seems highly unlikely that it will suddenly draw higher numbers than that.

Anyone might know a reason for this not-so-random draw? and is there a better way to get a random double that will more random than this?

Comment: How do you *draw* the numbers?

Comment: @vadian what do you mean? I do `Double.random(in: 0.0...5.0)`

Comment: I'd like to know what ***drawing*** means

Comment: just the result number. like the number that was chosen

Comment: As in drawing a card from a deck.

Comment: you may be able to "tune/extend" the drawing using this approach: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator

Comment: It's not reproducible on Xcode 13.2.1. The result of this line `print(Array(0..<100).map{_ in Double.random(in: 0.0...5.0)}.reduce(0.0, +) / 100)` should be always between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your issue. Here is the test code I used,
it gives a wide range of numbers between 0.0 and 5.0.
On macos 12.2-beta, using xcode 13.2, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("tesing")
            .onAppear {
                for i in 0...100 {
                    let x = drand48() * 5.0  // <-- alternative
                 //   let x = Double.random(in: 0.0 ... 5.0)
                    print("---> \(i) => \(x)")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate the issue either, but when I deploy the app the random numbers aren't random. I can't debug it since it works fine when I run it in debug

Comment: it's going to be tricky to debug, unless someone has come across this problem before. All the best.

Comment: you could try this, updated my answer with:
`import Foundation` and using `let x = drand48() * 5.0`

Answer (score 0):

The function `Double.random(in: 0.0...5.0)` seems fine and working on me when I try it on my playground, but if there's problem generating random double, try generating a random Int instead.

```swift
func randomDoubleFromInt() -> Double {
    let n1 = Int.random(in: 0...5)
    let n2 = Int.random(in: 0...9999999999)
    
    let nStr = "\(n1).\(n2)"
    
    return Double(nStr)!
}
```